# jQuery 1.4 .html() inserts unexpected whitespace in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, whitespace

I have a box displaying my shopping cart amount.
When the customer adds a new product I make a 
ajax request and send back the amount of products
in the cart. This looks like this:

```
...
success: function(data) {
  $("#basket div a").removeClass().addClass("active").empty().html(data +' Article');
} 
...
```

I started using jQuery 1.3 and everything worked
fine in all browsers. A couple of days ago I switched
to jQuery 1.4.1. Now I have a strange problem in all
IEs. Usually the box looks like this >
"9.articels". Since I switched to the current version
the box looks like this in IE > "9..........articles"
(dots simulate white-space).
It's like there are some hidden white spaces or whatever.
Hence I tried different options with CSS (white-space)
and also something with replace() but without success.

Does anyone have an idea why this strange behavior
occurs?

thx
Florian

Comment: is there a reason why you call .empty() then call .html()? rather than just set the .html()?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using the `.html()` function to set text. Do you get the same erroneous behaviour if you use the `.text()` function instead?

Generally I would only use the `.html()` function if the string you stipulate as the parameter is html.

Can you verify what the output of yoru request is. I.e. what is in `data`

Answer (score 1):

if your data is always a number, maybe try converting it to like this:

```
cess: function(data) {
  $("#basket div a").removeClass().addClass("active").empty().html(parseInt(data) +' Article');
```

note that I added this to your code, `parseInt(data)`

Comment: Don't forget to add the radix (10 for decimal): parseInt(data,10)

Comment: I'm happy to help. I'll be happier if you click the check on the right side. ;) cheers!